# How can I check if I made optimal mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, query-optimization

Are there any ways to check whether my Mysql database and PHP script are optimal? I want to figure it out and fix if it's possible till I publish it on internet for many users.

Comment: This is a very generic question. Optimal in what context? Database structure? Hits to server required? Speed of running? Lack of spaghetti code?

Comment: Speed of running the answer is.

Comment: If only there was a tool like this... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some benchmarking utility, like **apache benchmark, ab** to emulate some traffic to your site. If you have Apache server installed on your system, just switch to it's bin directory and run ab from there.

```
ab -n 100 -c 10 http://example.com/
```

and play with parameters and see.

But of course without an actual data and not on the real server the results will be just approximate.

Answer (score 0):

As Col. Shrapnel said, AB is a good start.

If you want to benchmark only your database, MySQL offers a nice benchmark suite.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-benchmarks.html